# Como ler um arquivo csv com caracteres com acentuação e transferir esses dados para um dicionário?

Tags: python-3.x, utf8-decode

Tenho um arquivo csv separado por ";" com duas colunas exportado via excel:

1) Nome da pessoa

2) e-mail da pessoa.

No entanto, o nome contém acentuação e ao tentar ler o arquivo e criar o dicionário, o python 3 (no macOS) dá erro no for. Como posso contornar isso? Vejam o código e o erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você não poderia converter todo arquivo para UTF8 ao invés de converter o conteúdo das linhas ?

Comment: E não poste o código em forma de imagem, isso impossibilita funcionar a busca do site sobre a pergunta.

Comment: Grato pela dica. Não postarei os códigos mais na forma de imagem.

Comment: Mesmo quando abro o arquivo com arq = open(pasta + "emails_alunos.csv", "r", encoding = 'utf-8'), dá erro no for. Apenas quando abro com arq = open(pasta + "emails_alunos.csv", "r", encoding = 'utf-8', errors='ignore') nao dá erro mas os caracteres com acento são ignorados. Como manter esses acentos.